Selenium Invalid Selector Exception
I am trying to click a button on a page.
<div class="button mt-8 text-center md:mt-12 lg:mt-16">
     <button class="cmp-button spacing-t-none spacing-b-none min-w-[12rem] justify-center bg-beige-200 text-black" type="button">
          <!---->
          <span class="cmp-button__text">View More</span>
     </button>
</div>

Here is the code I am using:
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium
import http.client
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from datetime import datetime as dt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


stuff = browser.find_element(
    By.CLASS_NAME,
    #'text-center md:mt-12 lg:mt-16'
    'cmp-button-spacing-t-none-spacing-b-none min-w-[12rem]-justify-center-bg-beige-200 text-black'
    #'cmp-button__text'
).click()

I have tried various combinations but I can't seem to click that button.
Any suggestions?
Edit #1:
If I use 'cmp-button__text', it seems to work, but it works on earlier values, not this particular one that I want. If only there was a way to reference this particular button. hmm...

You can use part of the classes when an element has many classes.
I give some XPath examples for this case. Please try the below XPath one by one to check whether it works:
By.XPATH, '//button[contains(@class,"cmp-button")]/span'

By.XPATH, '//span[text()="View More"]'

By.XPATH, '//button//span[text()="View More"]'

If these XPaths don't work, you may open the browser devtool, if an XPath in the devtool finds multiple elements. Update the XPath to make sure it locates a unique element.
